# twin.macro doesn't show css classes in UI and displaying message "You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using twin.macro in my React application and when I write css in Tailwind css way,
I am getting the message like this:
"You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).,[object Object]"

```
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState(
    theme`colors.white`
  );
 <header
      css={[
        css`
          background-color: ${backgroundColor};
          color: ${color};
        `,
        tw`w-full h-12 md:h-20 fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-40`
      ]}
    >
</header>
```

and HTML in Browser looks like:

```
<header css="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).,[object Object]" data-tw="w-full h-12 md:h-20 fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-40">
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. On each file that I was using the twin.macro css, I added
`/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` in the beginning.